# Inheritance in Islam

Tags: sharia, inheritance

I heard that in Islam a boy will not get anything from his grandfather's property if his (the boy's) father has died before the grandfather.

Shouldn't it be the other way round that the boy gets extra in case his father has passed away as he would be more needy compared to say his paternal cousin whose father is still alive?

Answer (score 1):

What you heard is incorrect. For example, if the son has passed away, and there are no parents:

- With one daughter: 1/2 to daughter, 1/2 to son of son.
- With more than one daughter: 2/3 to daughters equally and 1/3 to son of son.
- With no daughter: Son of son gets everything

The shares will change as per who is alive at the time. There are more cases to consider; the above is just an example.

Comment: does son of son get same as son of daughter?

Comment: @Honey — This is meant as an example to show that the claim is incorrect. If you are talking about a specific scenario, this will need to be a separate scenario. I am not clear on the son of daughter here is for a surviving daughter or not, a daughter that is eligible to inherit or not, etc.

Comment: I think the question meant to ask about sons blocking the inheritance of grandsons (nephews of the sons).

Comment: @Uma — My understanding is the boy who is allegedly not going to inherit is the grandson, whose father dies, and the grandfather is still alive. When the grandfather dies (not stated, but implied by "a boy will not get anything from his grandfather's property"), the boy (i.e., the grandchild) will not inherit from his grandfather. The question is not clear in any case, but in all of these cases, the boy will inherit.

Answer (score -1):

َAs you declared that "in case his father has passed away as he would be more needy compared to say his paternal cousin whose father is still alive?", so as I searched to some extent, I could find any related matter with your issue which be related to the needy situation of you. Since apparently the heritage has its specific laws which couldn't be so related to the financial situation of the heritor (AFAIK).